# Why does my code not return an error but still doesn't create a window?

Tags: python, pygal

When I run this code it doesn't return error but doesn't create a window. Somebody please help.

```
import pygal as pyg

line_chart = pyg.HorizontalBar()
line_chart.title = 'Friends favorite pizza topping'
line_chart.add('olives', 24)
line_chart.add('TOMATO', 32)
line_chart.add('pepperoni', 42)
line_chart.add('mushroom', 0.5)
line_chart.add('other', 1.5)
line_chart.render()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It generates SVG data which you can assign to variable

```
 data = line_chart.render()
```

and use to embed in HTML or to save in file

```
 with open('image.svg', 'wb') as fh:  # need binary mode
     fh.write(data)
```

or

```
 line_chart.render_to_file('image.svg')

 line_chart.render_to_png('image.png')
```

and later you can open it in browser or viewer.

If you want to see it at once in web browser then you need

```
 line_chart.render_in_browser()
```

There are other `render_....` to generate response for `Flask` and `Django`, etc.

---

Maybe if you use `render()` in `jupyter notebook` or `Google Colab` (which run in web browser) then it will display it at once.

---

```
import pygal as pyg

line_chart = pyg.HorizontalBar()
line_chart.title = 'Friends favorite pizza topping'
line_chart.add('olives', 24)
line_chart.add('TOMATO', 32)
line_chart.add('pepperoni', 42)
line_chart.add('mushroom', 0.5)
line_chart.add('other', 1.5)

data = line_chart.render(pretty_print=True)
print(data.decode())

with open('image.svg' 'wb') as fh:
    fh.write(data)
    
#line_chart.render_to_file('image.svg')
#line_chart.render_to_png('test.png')

line_chart.render_in browser()
```